# how to get spelling as an Input

Tags: actions-on-google

I know that google assistant can understand when I spell a word (e.g. "h-e-l-l-o"). How can I use this feature for my action? I want users to spell a word and I want to be able to get this as an input. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You would need to design a [custom scene](https://developers.google.com/assistant/conversational/scenes) that handles this. You could use slot filling to gather the input from the user, and then define the transition criteria based on what prompt is given.

You can get a feel for the conversational flow with user spelling input by looking at some of [the other available Actions based around spelling challenges](https://assistant.google.com/explore/search?q=spelling).